# How to end the program from a function which is called in another function (C++)

Tags: c++, function, exit

I have a loop of functions that I called like the code I wrote below and I want at some point to end the program.The problem is that I don't want to use exit function because I have data allocated dynamic also I could use an if in every function and exit one by one but I think will make the code a lot harder to understand and I have more than 3 functions like this.

```
void c()
{
     //code
     //I want to exit the program
}

void b()
{
     c();
     //code
}

void a()
{
     b();
     //code
}

int main()
{
     a();
     return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You want to exit but you don't want to exit?  What do you want to do then?  If you want to exit, just call `exit()` (or `_exit()` if you want to avoid `atexit` handlers).

Comment: A modern OS will put away all of your dynamically allocated storage and close file handles. `exit` may be perfectly safe for you to use  if you don't have something really sneaky going on (and if you do, add it to the question).

Comment: Optionally you could rely on [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) and throw an exception. That will unravel the call-stack destructing objects as it goes.

Comment: "...because I have data allocated dynamic.." dynamic memory is no longer an excuse to do anything unusual (not sure if it ever was though). Use containers and smart pointers. That being said, it is not clear what problem you are trying to solve. You want to exit but you dont want to `exit`, the example does not explain why

Comment: if you have things to do at exit, use the atexit() call to designate them. Then you can call exit() when needed and those things will still be done.

Comment: Not much detail here, but this sounds like **exactly** what exceptions are for.

Comment: In your case you should use `exception handling` so instead of calling `std::exit` you just throw an object of `std::exception` (derived class object) and in an `exception handler` you can gracefully exit the program.

Comment: I said that I don't want to use exit function because I read in another thread "Terminating the program without leaving the current block (e.g., by calling the function std::exit(int) (18.5)) does not destroy any objects with automatic storage duration (12.4)." Thanks for the answers I will read and use and exception handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `return` from all functions all the way to `main` (nicest).

You can call some variant of `exit`.

You can throw an exception.

You can use `setjmp`/`longjmp` to jump to the end of `main` (please don't).

You can crash the application (by calling `abort`, `raise(SIGKILL)` or similar).

I can't think of more options, but there may well be some...

Comment: `de-referencing` a null pointer is UB so how come you recommend that? A real program never depends on UBs or implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @Raindrop7 I'm certainly *not* recommending it. I'm just listing options. But yeah, that one should probably go. Will remove. Removed it - perhaps now you can also remove your downvote? 

Comment: @JesperJuhl I said in the initial message that i could do the first suggestion but "I think will make the code a lot harder to understand", the second suggestion I read that is not recommended to use it, so by elimination I will read on how to use and throw an exception.Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Inside your functions used `std::unique_ptr` wherever you need dynamic allocations.

Then modify :

```
int main()
{
     try
     {
          a();
     }
     catch(...) 
     { /*... */} 
     return 0;
 }
```

Then inside any of the *deep* functions, `throw` can be used, and `std::unique_ptr` will release the resources *auto-magically*.